# php array sorting with national signs and lowercase and uppercase letters

Tags: php, sorting, collation

As I can see, this problem has not been properly solved. I think I went through all the suggested solutions, but it was based on patching a specific problem. Which clearly, in my opinion, indicates a lack of PHP support for a correct solution to the basic, nastiest situation. It's about correct sorting (ascending or descending) for an array containing `lowercase and uppercase letters` and specific national characters. The solution below, which I am currently using, sorts lowercase and uppercase letters correctly but throws out national characters at the very end. None of you would like it. Array_multisort, mb_strcasecmp and collate are not working properly.

(pl-PL)

f.eg.

> balkon
> Bażant
> goleń
> Gęś
> Koza
> kuchnia
> mąka
> mięso
> Struś
> Wiewiórka
> Zając
> Łopian
> Świnia

```
        $file_info_all[] = [
        'taxon' => $taxon,
        'file_info_01c_text' => $file_info_01c_text
        ];      
    }
```

$file_info_01c_text <- this are my words to sorting

```
 usort($file_info_all, function ($a, $b) {
   return strcasecmp($a['file_info_01c_text'], $b['file_info_01c_text']);
    });
```

correct

> balkon
> Bażant
> Gęś
> goleń
> Koza
> kuchnia
> Łopian
> mąka
> mięso
> Struś
> Świnia
> Wiewiórka
> Zając

alphabet:
a **ą Ą** b c **ć Ć** d e **ę Ę** f g h i j k l **ł Ł** m n **ń Ń** o **ó Ó** p r s **ś Ś** t u v x y z **ż Ż ź Ź**

Answer (score 2):

The [intl Collator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.collator.php) does work:

```
$arr = explode(' ', 'balkon Bażant goleń Gęś Koza kuchnia mąka mięso Struś Wiewiórka Zając Łopian Świnia');
$collator = collator_create('pl');
usort($arr, fn($x, $y) => collator_compare($collator, $x, $y));
var_export($arr);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'balkon',
  1 => 'Bażant',
  2 => 'Gęś',
  3 => 'goleń',
  4 => 'Koza',
  5 => 'kuchnia',
  6 => 'Łopian',
  7 => 'mąka',
  8 => 'mięso',
  9 => 'Struś',
  10 => 'Świnia',
  11 => 'Wiewiórka',
  12 => 'Zając',
)
```

In your specific case, you can sort like this:

```
$file_info_all = [
    ['id' => 1, 'file_info_01c_text' => 'Bażant'],
    ['id' => 2, 'file_info_01c_text' => 'balkon']
];
$collator = collator_create('pl');
usort($file_info_all, fn($a, $b) => collator_compare($collator, $a['file_info_01c_text'], $b['file_info_01c_text']));
var_export($file_info_all);
```

Comment: Yes, it works elegantly. Thank you very much! Can you tell me how to combine this code with my array $file_info_all  - (file_info_01c_text)? Thnks.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. But your code works great. Many thanks and respect for your knowledge. Thank you very much.

Comment: @tropiciel It should work. Do you get an error or something?

Comment: @tropiciel I updated the answer with a full working example.

Comment: sorry, but I'm trying to understand the problem so I can know for the future. I already know where the problem is (that's why it didn't work for me) but I don't understand why. Problem -> $arr = $file_info_all;  usort($arr, fn($x, $y) // working ok -> usort($file_info_all, fn($x, $y) . After all, these are compatible codes.

Comment: When I use the solution with $arr - there is no sorting in any direction. When I use the solution with $file_info_all - all working fantastic.

Comment: @trop, here is the object-oriented version of this answer: https://3v4l.org/QIQIN